# Start non-blocking shell command in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

How can I start a non-blocking shell command in PowerShell? I can use Start-Process to start an executable but I have to split my parameters and it requires a full path instead of using the PATH variable.

I want to run something like:

```
Start-Process "npm run serve:dev"
```

instead of

```
Start-Process 'C:\\path\\to\\npm.exe' -ArgumentList "run", "serve:dev"
```

`Invoke-Expression` accepts a single string but that's not non-blocking.

Comment: Use PowerShell Jobs? If I catch your intention.

Comment: @Duncan That question doesn't work for me, because it recommends `Start-Process` which doesn't accept a single string. My question asks how to do it without using Start-Process.

Comment: @sashoalm read that question more carefully. The OP edited it to include a solution that takes a single string.